# Is there any non-Advaita interpretation of Yoga Vasistha?

Tags: vedanta, yoga-vashishtha

Yoga Vasistha is usually considered an advaitic text but is there any non-advatic interpretation of this holy text?

Comment: Great question. I upvoted it. Personally I am not aware of any non-advaitic work on this text. This is not accepted by many Vaishnava schools, and given its content that favours Advaitic constructs, I doubt there is any non-advaitic interpretations.  When it comes to The Vedas, all the schools would have interpreted in their own way because all the schools tried to find The Vedic backing for their system of philosophy (systems that claim to be The Vedantic schools as opposed to tantric etc). But when it comes to texts like yOga vAsishtam, they probably didn't feel the need to comment on it

Comment: @Vidyarthi Actually Yoga Vasistha is usually thought of as a Advatic text. Maybe it's naturally favors Advaita but I am not really sure . Just wanted to know about other schools thought on this book.

Comment: One interpretation as per Gaudiya, i.e., the 'Achintya Bheda-Abedha School of Thought' - is to completely reject Yoga Vasistha as explained in [This Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46425/what-is-iskcons-view-on-yoga-vasista/46493#46493)